# Should I purchase the Windows 8 backup DVD?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I'm running the Windows 8 update wizard to upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8. There is an option to also purchase the Windows 8 backup DVD. What I need to do is to install Windows 8 from scratch, partitioning the filesystem again. I used to do this using the CD of Windows XP, but now I don't know if I have to purchase the DVD of Windows 8 for this task.

So my questions are:

- Should I need to purchase the backup DVD?
- Will I be able to burn a DVD of Windows 8 if I don't buy it?
- Will I be able to partition my disk and install Windows 8 from scratch without a DVD of Windows 8?

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need a CD anymore with Windows 8 (for most circumstances) - the is an option in System Settings to revert the machine back to its original state.

Comment: Why would you purchase it when you can download and make one yourself for free?  You cannot install Windows 8 without an existing copy unless you have a System Builder license.  So no matter what you will have to install a legit installation of a previous installation of windows.

Comment: Does it mean that I can't repartition my filesystem as I want? I can't even install ubuntu because it does not recognize actual partitions... I guess that the System Builder license is more expensive, isnt it?

Comment: The Update Assistant will allow you to create a Win8 Setup DVD/USB, which you can use to boot from and repartition/reformat, *as long as you have a valid qualifying version of Windows (i.e. XP+) installed on the system*.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the disk you are talking about is for recovery purposes. If you want to insure your computer against a hard drive crash i would say get the disk. I know that as a pc tech it makes it alot easier on us to get your new hard drive running if you have your own disks